# How to change padding of Material UI's datepicker?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-mirzakhani-ewb01?file=/src/DatePickerDemo.tsx) is the codesandbox link

```js
function InlineDatePickerDemo(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          style={{ padding: "20px" }}
          autoOk
          variant="inline"
          inputVariant="outlined"
          label="With keyboard"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          value={selectedDate}
          InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }}
          onChange={(date) => handleDateChange(date)}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

I want to reduce the gapping inside the date-picker box but giving custom styles is not affecting.

I am curious to know why style is not working and what could be the solution for such problem.

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site.

Comment: I have included codesandbox with all relevant code not any external site. What else you want to know?

Comment: codesandbox.io != stackoverflow.com so therefore it is an external site. Not sure how that's not obvious. @NearHuscarl copied the code from codesandbox to this site, relicensing your code under CC-by-SA 4.0. You should have done that as the copyright holder.

Comment: I did not know that It is mandatory to include code here if sandbox code is already provided because that is more helpful and asked for (in most cases) and that's why I was putting emphasis on codesandbox that It is not just any website, It is more than that. Anyway, really sorry for the trouble, I will keep this in mind while posting any question here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you did is styling the parent component. In order to change the spacing between the components inside the picker, you need to override the following classes in the sub-components:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      padding: 0,
      "& .MuiButtonBase-root": {
        padding: 0,
        paddingLeft: 10
      },
      "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
        padding: 15,
        paddingLeft: 0
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```js
const classes = useStyles();

return (
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardDatePicker
      className={classes.root}
      {...}
    />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64336432/how-to-change-padding-of-material-uis-datepicker]

Comment: This will work, but when using webpack production build, MUI classnames will be converted to an alphanumeric string, and this will no longer work. Had to really on the HTML elements instead.

Comment: @Nicole that's weird because normally the className won't be changed in producttion if it starts with `Mui`. See [this](https://mui.com/styles/advanced/#default).