# Material ui - cannot override datepicker style using makeStyles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add border for the datepicker below.
When I apple inline style in Web inspector, it works.
[image]

But when I try to apply the style using `makeStyles`,
nothing happens.

demo.js

```
import "date-fns";
import React from "react";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardTimePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export const styles = makeStyles(() => ({
  formControl: {
    border: "1px solid grey"
  }
}));

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const classes = styles();
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(
    new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
  );

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardTimePicker
        margin="normal"
        id="time-picker"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        KeyboardButtonProps={{
          "aria-label": "change time"
        }}
        classes={{
          formControl: classes.formControl
        }}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-viq2m?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1):

If you check the log, you will see

[image]

As [KeyboardTimePicker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardTimePicker) is inherited from TextField, and while TextField CSS API only accepts `root` ([reference](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#css)), so the solution is to update the `formControl` key to `root`

```
      <KeyboardTimePicker
        margin="normal"
        id="time-picker"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        KeyboardButtonProps={{
          "aria-label": "change time"
        }}
        classes={{
          root: classes.formControl
        }}
      />
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

That's because `@material-ui/pickers` is a separate development on top of MUI.

> Date/Time pickers are quite simple controls from UX perspective, so
> most people just use the default appearance
>
> That's why we are not providing any for-component classes api to
> override stylesheets for any particular component. The only way to
> override existing stylesheets are with the use of global material-ui
> theme overrides.

That's as per their [docs](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/css-overrides).

I have set up an example with a red border.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wgpvf?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution which is different from other answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336432/how-to-change-padding-of-material-uis-datepicker)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      border: "1px solid red",
    }
  }
});
```

```
const classes = useStyles();

return (
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardDatePicker
      className={classes.root}
      {...}
    />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
);
```

I think this is also one of the solutions.